# How to disable Open Directory to startup with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, open-directory

I was recently given a computer by the IT dept. at my company, right before the IT guy left for a few days... However it isn't configured to be used:

[image]

From what I understand this is called "Open Directory". I don't need it for the work I'm doing. How do I start the computer with the "normal" Mac OS X?

**I do not have a way to go past the prompt.**

I couldn't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my opinion - as a SysAdmin/Mac supporter - this is a really bad hack and it is not recommended. But it works!**

You probably can forcefully unbind your Mac and reconfigure it by using the .AppleSetupDone method. This may "poison" the Open Directory though, because your Mac isn't properly unbound from the *disconnected/non-reachable* OD server.

1. Reboot to Single User Mode with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
2. Enter `/sbin/fsck -fy`
3. Enter `/sbin/mount -uw /`
4. Enter `rm -r /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/`
5. Enter `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

On the first attempt this didn't work for me – I got some override root messages. Simply enter `yes` then. This doesn't remove the files/folder in question though. I repeated the last three steps but accidentally entered `/sbin/mount -rw /` (which doesn't mean read-write but read-only followed by a read/write) as first command.

6. Enter `/sbin/mount -rw /` (`/sbin/mount -w /` should also work but that's **unclear**)
7. Enter `rm -r /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService/`
8. Enter `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

After a reboot (`shutdown -r now`) you should get the Config Assistant and create a new local admin account.

---

After setting up the new admin user, open System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Network Account Server. You probably have to remove any listed OD to properly work with your local admin account.

Comment: By "poison" the Open Directory" do you mean other people in the office might have their workflow affected? Or just the person who was using this computer with this setup? (Who no longer will)

Comment: On step 1 I get "ERROR: volume / is mounted with write access. Re-run with (-l) to freeze volume."

Comment: @MicroMachine You have to completely reboot to SU Mode before executing the commands.

Comment: @MicroMachine Poisoning means that your Mac as an entity still is in the OD database, but your real Mac isn't joined anymore.

Comment: What is the proper command to type in when it asks "override rwxr-rx-x root/wheel for /Library/Preferences/DirectoryServices/"?

Comment: Enter `/sbin/mount -w /` or `/sbin/mount -rw /` like mentioned in my answer: "On the first attempt..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60412/discussion-between-micromachine-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 0):

The network accounts are related to open directory, but to show the "normal" MacOS login page, you don't actually need to disable it. Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups. You will see this image (except your Username will be highlighted):

[image]

Click on Login Options. If the padlock bottom left is closed, almost everything will be greyed out (like it is now). If the lock is closed and you do not have administrative privileges on your computer, you will want to talk to your IT department. If the lock is closed but you do have administrative privileges, click on the lock to unlock the settings by typing in your administrative username and password.

Once the selections are no longer greyed out, change the "Display login window as:" selection from "Name and password" to "List of users".

**EDIT based on subsequent information:**

Let's assume you can't get to System Preferences because you can't get into your computer. We then follow these steps.

Do you have a local user account or a Network account? If you have a local account, you should be able to type in your username and password to get past the prompt. If you have a network account, try connecting to wifi (I think there is a wifi icon in the top right corner you can use without logging in, or plug in an ethernet cable. Then log in with your network account. If you have NO account information (you were never assigned/told/asked to create a log-in or password) we can't help you - you'll have to wait for the IT guy to get back.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, I do not have any way to bypass the prompt - no ID, no password (until IT guy returns). No System Preferences seem accessible...

Comment: @MicroMachine Do you have a local user account or a Network account? If you have a local account, you should be able to type in your username and password to get past the prompt. If you have a network account, try connecting to wifi (I think there is a wifi icon in the top right corner you can use without logging in, or plug in an ethernet cable. Then log in with your network account. If you have NO account information (you were never assigned/told/asked to create a log-in or password) we can't help you - you'll have to wait for the IT guy to get back.

Comment: The last part of this comment applies. Thanks. If you can, add this to the answer so I can accept it

Comment: @MicroMachine edited

Comment: Yes. I have no info to type in the boxes. Also, couldn't I start from bootable device?

Comment: @klanomath how do I type this terminal command from the login prompt screen?

Comment: @MicroMachine Boot to single user mode (cmd-S). Then enter `/sbin/mount -uw /`, `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` and finally reboot with `shutdown -r now`. You probably will be asked to create a new account then. I recommend to wait few minutes until I'm done testing this.

Comment: @klanomath so...? Does it work?

Comment: @MicroMachine It should work with some mods. I will write an answer

Comment: @klanomath should I remove this answer, as it does not fix OPs problem?

Comment: @NoahL I like your answer because eventually I might look into disabling this... someone might anyways.

Comment: @NoahL I think my answer is a really bad hack... Waiting for the admin is the proper answer (from my SysAdmin view)

Comment: @klanomath Your answer needs to be out there for people like me who can't wait for R. from IT to come back on the 23rd, and have work to do :P

Comment: @klanomath also I tried it and it said "rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone no such file or directory"